# Правильно ли выполняется проверка на то что флаги совпадают?

Tags: c#, битовые-операции

Имеется E'нумератор помеченный аттрибутом `[Flags]`:

```
[Flags]
public enum InitFlags : uint
{
    Timer = 0x00000001u,
    Audio = 0x00000010u,
    Video = 0x00000020u,
    Joystick = 0x00000200u,
    Haptic = 0x00001000u,
    GameController = 0x00002000u,
    Events = 0x00004000u,
    [Obsolete("Compatibility; this flag is ignored.", false)]
    NoParachute = 0x00100000u,
    Everything = Timer | Audio | Video | Joystick | Haptic | GameController | Events
}
```

Пытаюсь выполнить тест на все что было инициализировано:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WasInit_Test()
{
    List<InitFlags> flags = new List<InitFlags>
    {
        InitFlags.Timer,
        InitFlags.Audio,
        InitFlags.Video,
        InitFlags.Joystick,
        InitFlags.Haptic,
        InitFlags.GameController,
        InitFlags.Events,
        InitFlags.Everything
    };

    foreach (InitFlags initFlag in flags.SkipWhile(initFlags =>
        initFlags == InitFlags.Everything || initFlags == InitFlags.NoParachute))
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(0, _initSubSystem(initFlag));
        if (initFlag == InitFlags.Everything)
        {
            foreach (InitFlags initializedFlag in flags.SkipWhile(initFlags =>
                initFlags == InitFlags.Everything || initFlags == InitFlags.NoParachute))
                Assert.IsTrue((initializedFlag & initFlag) == initializedFlag);
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(_wasInit.Invoke(initFlag) == initFlag);
        _quitSubSystem(initFlag);
    }
}
```

Тест завершается успехом, но я не сильно разбираюсь с работой флагов.

`_wasInit` это делегат на неуправляемую процедуру, в ее правильной работе можно не сомневаться.

Comment: в чем смысл skipWhile тут?

Comment: *"тест на все что было инициализировано"* - смысл этой фразы слишком неочевиден

Comment: тут скорее надо разбить на два теста: 1 - что `_wasInit.Invoke(initFlag) == initFlag` для всех указанных флагов, а второй, что в InitFlags.Everything все имеющиеся выставлены

Comment: @VTT: `_initSubSystem` с флагом `Everything` может вернуть 0, даже когда одна из указанных подсистем не была инициализирована.

Comment: Что это за процедуры-то? Тут совершенно непонятно, что этот код должен делать, и в каком конкретном месте выполняется подозрительная проверка.

Comment: Ваш цикл выполнится только один раз. Так и было задумано? Классическая проверка наличия флага: `if (initFlags  & InitFlags.Audio == InitFlags.Audio)` или его отсутствия: `if (initFlags  & InitFlags.Audio == 0)`. Как-то странно у вас тут все выглядит...